# KeyPress does not seems to work when testcafe is set as docker agent in Jenkins

Tags: docker, jenkins, testing, automated-tests, testcafe

I decided to take a random site for testing, so in this case, it is www.nike.com

**Testing scope**:

1. Go to www.nike.com
2. Type 'Men' in the quick search on the top right of the page.
3. Press Enter
4. Validate whether search results are greater than 10

test.js

```
fixture `Nike.com`// declare the fixture
    .page `www.nike.com`;  // specify the start page

const nameInput = Selector('.product-card.css-ucpg4q.ncss-col-sm-6.ncss-col-lg-4.va-sm-t.product-grid__card');
const searchGlass = Selector('.g72-search.fs20-nav-sm');

//then create a test and place your code there
test('Scenario-1: Validate Quick Search Functionality for Men', async t => {
    await t
        .maximizeWindow()
        .typeText('#TypeaheadSearchInput', 'Men')
        .pressKey('enter');
        //.click(searchGlass);
        const nameInputElement = await nameInput.with({ visibilityCheck: true })();
    await t    
        .takeScreenshot()
        // Use the assertion to check if the actual header text is equal to the expected one
        .expect(Selector('.product-card.css-ucpg4q.ncss-col-sm-6.ncss-col-lg-4.va-sm-t.product-grid__card').count).gt(10, 'Search results must be more than 10');

});
```

Jenkinsfile

```
stage('Install') {          
            agent {
                docker {
                    image 'node:10.11'
                    reuseNode true
                }
            }
            environment {
                HOME = '.'
            }

            steps {
                sh 'npm config set unsafe-perm true'                
                sh 'npm install testcafe-reporter-html'
            }           
        }
stage('Test'){
            agent { 
                docker {
                        image 'testcafe/testcafe:alpha'
                        args '-e NODE_PATH=./node_modules'
                        args '--entrypoint=\'\''
                        reuseNode true
                } 
            }

            steps{
                sh "node_modules/.bin/testcafe 'chromium:headless --no-sandbox --disable-dev-shm-usage' ./tests/test.js -s takeOnFails=true -r html:reports/results.html"
            }
        }
```

**Issues**:

1. KeyPress('Enter') is not working. Text is typed in quick search but enter key is not pressed. I was able to validate this by taking a screenshot.
2. As a work-around, I thought of avoiding keypress and instead do a mouse click on the search icon(searchglass in the code snippet I have shared) in the test.js

**Although, test is able to click on search icon, it is actually, giving error in html report **
*Error on page "https://www.nike.com/w?q=Men&vst=Men":

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'cancelled' of null

Browser: HeadlessChrome 77.0.3865 / Linux 0.0.*

The weird part is everything is working fine on my laptop with testcafe docker running on my laptop. The HTML report is showing results as expected too. I cannot seem to find why the weird behavior when tests are running from Jenkins via testcafe docker agent.

Comment: After few experiments and trail & error, I was able to get rid of the issue. I had to pass args '--net=host -e DISPLAY=":0"' to docker agent.

I have copied the entire jenkinsfile here for someone who is interested to look at it. https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/4481

Comment: If you have found the solution then we invite you to write an answer

Answer (score 1):

After few experiments and trail & error, I was able to get rid of the issue. I had to pass args '--net=host -e DISPLAY=":0"' to docker agent.

I am copying the entire jenkins file if someone is interested.

```
pipeline {

    agent any

    stages {
        stage('Install') {          
            agent {
                docker {
                    image 'node:10.11'
                    reuseNode true
                }
            }
            environment {
                HOME = '.'
            }

            steps {
                sh 'npm config set unsafe-perm true'                
                sh 'npm install testcafe-reporter-html'
                sh 'npm install testcafe-reporter-junit'
            }           
        }
        stage('Test'){
            agent { 
                docker {
                        image 'testcafe/testcafe'
                        args  '--net=host -e DISPLAY=":0"'
                        args '-e NODE_PATH=./node_modules'
                        args '--entrypoint=\'\''
                        reuseNode true
                } 
            }

            steps{
                sh "node_modules/.bin/testcafe 'chromium:headless --no-sandbox --disable-dev-shm-usage' ./tests/test.js -s -r html:results.html,junit:report.xml"
            }
        }       
    }
    post {
        always {
            echo 'Use this stage to do post run activities'
            deleteDir() /* clean up our workspace */
        }
    }
}
```